# Postgres Full Outer Join headscratcher

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

If I write a query like this:

```
with foo as (
    select
        'foo' as name,
        1 as value
    union all select
        'foo', 2
    union all select
        'foo', 3
    union all select
        'foo', 4
), bar as (
    select
        'bar' as name,
        3 as value
    union all select
        'bar', 4
    union all select
        'bar', 5
    union all select
        'bar', 6
)
select
    f.name,
    b.value,
    b.name
from
    foo as f
full outer join
    bar as b
    on b.value = f.value;
```

I get this:

```
name        value    name
foo         (null)  (null)
foo         (null)  (null)
foo         3       bar
foo         4       bar
(null)      5       bar
(null)      6       bar
```

this is what I expect.  But if I try to do something similar with a table-valued function like so:

```
with allSizes as (
        select cast('120X60' as character varying) as size
        union all select '160X600'
        union all select '1X1'
        union all select '300X250'
        union all select '728X90'
        union all select '88X32'
        union all select 'PEEL'
)
select
        msd.region,
        msd.market,
        s.size,
        msd.target,
        msd.actual
from 
        marketdata('2013-01-05') as msd
full outer join
        allSizes as s
        on s.size = msd.size
where
        msd.market = 'Foo, USA';
```

where `marketdata()` is a table-valued function, I do not get empty rows corresponding to the `size` column that are not present in the `marketdata()` function.  Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of:

```
where
        msd.market = 'Foo, USA';
```

It produces the `full outer join` and then filters out the rows that are not present in the `marketdata()` (because they have `msd.market` = `NULL`)

You may change the query to:

```
with allSizes as (
        select cast('120X60' as character varying) as size
        union all select '160X600'
        union all select '1X1'
        union all select '300X250'
        union all select '728X90'
        union all select '88X32'
        union all select 'PEEL'
)
select
        msd.region,
        msd.market,
        s.size,
        msd.target,
        msd.actual
from 
        (select marketdata('2013-01-05')
         where  market = 'Foo, USA') as msd
full outer join
        allSizes as s
        on s.size = msd.size;
```

Or simply rewrite

```
where
        msd.market = 'Foo, USA' OR msd.market IS NULL;
```

If `marketdata()` returns no rows with `msd.market IS NULL`.

Comment: Hah!  obvious now.  I rarely need to use full joins so I was overthinking it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: this would be true for a "normal" left or right outer join as well (if a column of the "outer" table is part of the where clause).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yeah that's why I said it was obvious now.  Allow that a person can have a brain failure once in a while.  :)